# Duda en clases de Swing Relación de Herencia JComponent y ActionEvent

Tags: java, java-swing

antes que nada pongo el código:

Inicio.java

```
public class Inicio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
    }
}
```

Ventana.java

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuBar barra_menu; 
    private JMenu opcion1;
    private JMenu opcion2;
    private JMenu opcion3;
    private JMenuItem opcion11;
    private JMenuItem opcion12;
    private JMenuItem opcion13;
    private JMenuItem opcion21;
    private JMenuItem opcion22;
    private JMenuItem opcion31;
    private JMenuItem opcion32;

    public Ventana() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 200, 400, 500);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        crear_interfaz();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void crear_interfaz() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        barra_menu = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(barra_menu);

        opcion1 = new JMenu("Archivo");
        barra_menu.add(opcion1);

        opcion11 = new JMenuItem("Abrir");
        opcion1.add(opcion11);

        opcion12 = new JMenuItem("Cerrar");
        opcion1.add(opcion12);

        opcion13 = new JMenuItem("Salir");
        opcion1.add(opcion13);

        opcion2 = new JMenu("Clientes");
        barra_menu.add(opcion2);

        opcion21 = new JMenuItem("Gestión");
        opcion2.add(opcion21);

        opcion22 = new JMenuItem("Facturar");
        opcion2.add(opcion22);

        opcion3 = new JMenu("Ayuda");
        barra_menu.add(opcion3);

        opcion31 = new JMenuItem("Ayuda");
        opcion3.add(opcion31);

        opcion32 = new JMenuItem("Acerca de ...");
        opcion3.add(opcion32);

        opcion11.setName("opcion11");
        opcion12.setName("opcion12");
        opcion13.setName("opcion13");
        opcion21.setName("opcion21");
        opcion22.setName("opcion22");
        opcion31.setName("opcion31");
        opcion32.setName("opcion32");

        opcion11.addActionListener(this);
        opcion12.addActionListener(this);
        opcion13.addActionListener(this);
        opcion21.addActionListener(this);
        opcion22.addActionListener(this);
        opcion31.addActionListener(this);
        opcion32.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String opcion_seleccionada = ((JComponent)e.getSource()).getName();
        System.out.println(opcion_seleccionada);
    }
}
```

El código funciona y muestra la traza por consola de la opción del menú seleccionada. Ahora bien, no entiendo por qué se puede hacer eso:

```
((JComponent)e.getSource()).getName();
```

No veo ninguna relación de herencia entre ActionEvent y JComponent, entonces por qué se puede castear un ActionEvent en un JComponent?

Gracias de antemano.

Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Deberias añadir el codigo donde aparezca la declaracion de e y demas...

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no le estas haciendo un casting a un objeto ActionEvent (e).

El código es el siguiente:

```
(JComponent)e.getSource()..
```

Es decir el casting lo haces sobre el resultado de e.getSource(), el cual es un componente que contiene a ese evento. Puedes mirar la documentación [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource())

Para hacer el casting a (e) el ActionEvent el código seria el siguiente:

```
((JComponent)(e)).getSource()...
```

En este caso habría que englobar al objeto y casting, juntos entre paréntesis. Y entonces poder llamar al método "getSource" de JComponent. ¡Obviamente!, este no es el caso y daría un error de casteo.